# Command to monitor network traffic

Tags: networking, network-monitoring

I want to know the command used in this screenshot to monitor the active traffic to a web server. This looks like netstat but i am unable to print all the info with it. This screenshot is from the movie 'The Social Network'.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must be apachetop

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/monitor-your-website-in-real-time-with-apachetop/

Answer (score 1):

Apache tomcat allows monitoring of http sessions and connections using apache tomcat manager user @ http://:/manager.html (might be manager.htm, not too sure about this). 
Also netstat -lptu allows monitoring of connections (ports opened) by any process (supply pid), use web-server's pid to get this.

Hope this helps.